# Got exceptions after upgrading environment to use JasperReports with Java 8 and new jdt compiler

Tags: java, java-8, jasper-reports, eclipse-jdt

I want to generate *JasperReports*'s report by using my *jrxml* and *Java* code. 
I'm using Netbeans 8 and jdk8.

I got a lot of exceptions during template compilation:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: 
Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. java.lang.Integer cannot be resolved or is not a type
                value = new java.lang.Integer(1); //$JR_EXPR_ID=0$
                                <--------------->
java.util.Date cannot be resolved or is not a type
                value = new java.util.Date(); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                            <------------>
java.sql.Connection cannot be resolved or is not a type
                value = ((java.sql.Connection)parameter_REPORT_CONNECTION.getValue()); //$JR_EXPR_ID=21$
                          <----------------->
```

I've already added *jdt* jar files.

The full list of jar files:

- org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.1
- jdtcore-3.1.0
- org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.11.1.v20150902-1521
- jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.9
- jtds-1.3.1
- jdt-0.15.0

How to fix this issue?

Comment: It's looking the reason is jdk8. did you try older version of jdk? e.g 1.7.80

Answer (score 0):

only `jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.9.jar` is required. above listed .jar files are not necessary.
i add new jasper library but not removed old jar.
so please remove old jar first than add latest version of jar.